# How to upgrade numpy and pip version 18.1 to version 19.1.1 on mac?

Tags: python

I'm trying to upgrade numpy on mac but all commands I've found doesn't work.

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip4 install numpy
pip install numpy --upgrade --ignore-installed
pip install numpy --upgrade
pip install -U numpy
$ sudo port install py26-numpy, 
-> command not found

python -m pip install --upgrade pip
python -m pip3 install --upgrade pip3
python -m pip install SomePackage
-> no module named pip/pip3
```

`pip3 install numpy`
this is the command I used, and I have no idea what is going on. Please help me

Answer (score 1):

The best practices is to create a [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io) first. It is a tool to create isolated Python environments. Than way you don’t pollute your system-wide Python.

```
python3 -m venv yourvenv
source yourvenv/bin/activate
```

Then, you can upgrade [pip](https://pip.pypa.io) (the Python packages installer), but it is not a requirement.

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Now, you can install numpy:

```
pip install numpy
```

Comment: I have no idea how it works but that codes actually do something wow thank youuu